# How to rewrite the undefined function each() correctly in this case?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, foreach, each

Updating PHP on old WordPress website got an Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in 186 line of class-vc-mapper.php

```
public function callElementActivities( $tag ) {
        do_action( 'vc_mapper_call_activities_before' );
        if ( isset( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) ) {
                while ( $activity = each( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) ) {  << line
                list ( $method, $params ) = $activity[1];
                switch ( $method ) {
                    case 'drop_param':
                        WPBMap::dropParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute_name'] );
                        break;
                    case 'add_param':
                        WPBMap::addParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                        break;
                    case 'mutate_param':
                        WPBMap::mutateParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                        break;
                    case 'drop_shortcode':
                        WPBMap::dropShortcode( $params['name'] );
                        break;
                    case 'modify':
                        WPBMap::modify( $params['name'], $params['setting_name'], $params['value'] );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I believe that it should be changed for 'foreach' but I don't know how to do it correctly.
Pls help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`each()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) has been **deprecated** as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Also note that `each()` function is typically used in conjunction with `list()` to traverse an array.

So the alternative is to use the `foreach()` function on the array **key** / **value** pairs *(but not only the **values**)*, to traverse `$this->element_activities[ $tag ]` array.

So the correct revisited working code should be:

```
public function callElementActivities( $tag ) {
    do_action( 'vc_mapper_call_activities_before' );

    if ( isset( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] as $method => $params ) {
            switch ( $method ) {
                case 'drop_param':
                    WPBMap::dropParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute_name'] );
                    break;
                case 'add_param':
                    WPBMap::addParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'mutate_param':
                    WPBMap::mutateParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'drop_shortcode':
                    WPBMap::dropShortcode( $params['name'] );
                    break;
                case 'modify':
                    WPBMap::modify( $params['name'], $params['setting_name'], $params['value'] );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IT should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function callElementActivities( $tag ) {
    do_action( 'vc_mapper_call_activities_before' );
    if ( isset( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] as $activity ) {
            list ( $method, $params ) = $activity;
            switch ( $method ) {
                case 'drop_param':
                    WPBMap::dropParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute_name'] );
                    break;
                case 'add_param':
                    WPBMap::addParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'mutate_param':
                    WPBMap::mutateParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'drop_shortcode':
                    WPBMap::dropShortcode( $params['name'] );
                    break;
                case 'modify':
                    WPBMap::modify( $params['name'], $params['setting_name'], $params['value'] );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, mate @TheKajtek. Now another error poped-up: Unedifying array in that line:
 list ( $method, $params ) = $activity[1]
Maybe you can help me with that also?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).